# Android Studio :: Gradle Scripts Error Android()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, compiler-errors

I use this following script under my current android project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

android {
    compileSdkVersion 11
    buildToolsVersion "11.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 11
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But then found this error message.
[image: This error]

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `android` block should be within a module `build.gradle` that contains `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`, and not in the root `build.gradle` file.

Example:

root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

module `build.gradle` (could be within the `app` folder):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 11
    buildToolsVersion "11.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 11
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```